# Docker simple file sharing host<>docker

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. I'm trying to achive to run a docker and add some files. The user should be able to change this files and let the docker do it's magic. Performance is not important, but simplicity. It should be possible to run the docker without further arguments, only "-it". I tried to use Volumes, but ...

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

volumes:
  data:
    name: templatevolume

services:
  template:
    image: template
    volumes:
        - data:/usr/template/:rw
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

... the Volume will be created, but not assigned to the Docker. Is there a better way? Do I need to assign the Volume to the Docker within the run command? Please advice.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:latest

LABEL Name=template Version=0.0.1

...
```

it's a long Dockerfile, but I do nothing with Volumes here and nothing special, only install packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind mounts. They will mount a directory of your physical machine into your docker container.

For such volume you need to specify **source**  of the mount, which is the path to the file or directory on the Docker daemon host (your computer) and **target**, which is the path where the file or directory is mounted in the container (inside the container).

```
- "source:target"
```

You don't need to create any docker volumes at all.

Let's create a [hidden directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) *.data* in the directory of your docker-compose yml file

```
$ mkdir .data
```

You docker-compose file now:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  template:
    image: template
    volumes:
        - data:/usr/template/:rw
        - "./.data:/usr/template/"
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

That's it. A user can have access to the files in *.data* and docker also can work with all the content there.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work, do I need something like that to make it work? $ docker run -d \
  --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/dockertest/,target=/var/www/test
I trying to avoid, to mount it via CLI